# Panda: Dropping rows after concat string of 2 rows

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I like to check a column, if the column date is the same as the next, combine the remark column. The date rows could be more than 2.

My current code is stuck at this stage:

```
df = {'date': ['02-Jan','02-Jan','03-Jan','03-Jan','03-Jan','04-Jan','05-Jan'],
       'remarks':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
for eachRow in range(len(df)):
    print("row" , eachRow)
    try:
        if(df['date'][eachRow] == df['date'][eachRow + 1]):
            df['remarks'][eachRow] = df['remarks'][eachRow] + df['remarks'][eachRow + 1]
            print('drop', eachRow+1)
            df = df.drop(eachRow + 1) 
            print(df)
    except:
        print(df)
```

My output current is. I noticed when I have more than 2 consecutive rows with same date, and when I drop row 3, I cannot check row 2 and row 4 because my eachRow pointer has move to row 3 and there is nothing for row 3 to compare. If I chose not to drop the next row, I will have duplicated rows with incorrect remarks. How can I go about this?

```
row 0
drop 1
     date remarks
0  02-Jan      ab
2  03-Jan       c
3  03-Jan       d
4  03-Jan       e
5  04-Jan       f
6  05-Jan       g
row 1
     date remarks
0  02-Jan      ab
2  03-Jan       c
3  03-Jan       d
4  03-Jan       e
5  04-Jan       f
6  05-Jan       g
row 2
drop 3
     date remarks
0  02-Jan      ab
2  03-Jan      cd
4  03-Jan       e
5  04-Jan       f
6  05-Jan       g
row 3
     date remarks
0  02-Jan      ab
2  03-Jan      cd
4  03-Jan       e
5  04-Jan       f
6  05-Jan       g
row 4
row 5
row 6
     date remarks
0  02-Jan      ab
2  03-Jan      cd
4  03-Jan       e
5  04-Jan       f
6  05-Jan       g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple change can save it:

Instead of dropping the next row (`eachRow+1`), drop current row (`eachRow`):

`df = df.drop(eachRow)`;

At the same time, you must note that concatenation has to be made in the next row, as you are dropping the current row. Hence, change the line to:

`df['remarks'][eachRow+1] = df['remarks'][eachRow] + df['remarks'][eachRow + 1]`

```
df = {'date': ['02-Jan','02-Jan','03-Jan','03-Jan','03-Jan','04-Jan','05-Jan'],
       'remarks':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
for eachRow in range(len(df)):
    print("row" , eachRow)
    try:
        if(df['date'][eachRow] == df['date'][eachRow + 1]):
            df['remarks'][eachRow+1] = df['remarks'][eachRow] + df['remarks'][eachRow + 1]
            print('drop', eachRow)
            df = df.drop(eachRow)
            print(df)
    except:
        print(df)
```